# Contacts Picker issue

Tags: android, contacts, picker

I'm new to Android programming and I'm trying to see some examples in the internet to understand the general idea of Android development .

Actually, I'm facing a issue since a week. I'm trying to run " An Android Contacts Picker" project. But, if I press "Invite contacts" and browse the contacts, a message appears " No email found " !

Here is the tutorial
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker/

Here is the Code:
http://code.google.com/p/android-send-message-tutorial-code/downloads/detail?name=send-message-code-5.zip&can=2&q=

This issue drives me crazy ! It works with everyone in the earth "As shown in the comments " except me !

For Debugging, I used my Galaxy nexus and the Android emulator.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Verify you have contacts in your emulator (In case) with 'email id' which you are going to invite. While debugging ensure that you give a email id that is existing in your contact.

Comment: Are you using emulator. If yes, then by default emulator does not have any email account registered. So it possibly will not have any contacts unless you add it manually. That's may be a reason you are getting "No email found"

Comment: Sure, I've added contacts with "email id" in my emulator. Even thought, doesn't work :(